# SELECT only the top unique results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to grab only 1 value for each unique componentID (so the top 2 rows result from the image would be the perfect result).

```
SELECT cs.ID ,AvgStatisticData ,cs.ComponentID 
FROM PortEvidence pe
JOIN ComponentStatus cs ON cs.ID=pe.ComponentStatusID
JOIN Component c ON c.ComponentID= cs.ComponentID
WHERE c.ComponentType = 48 
ORDER BY cs.ID DESC
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Add to existing query  row_number () over (partition by componentid order by id desc) as rn Then make that a sub  query and add an outer select *from (sun) where rn=1 .  Each highest Id for each component?

Comment: @xQbert I was considering that. Would it be impossible to pull off without that?

Comment: No there are other ways such as using cross apply or lateral if supported or an old school way of select max(Id) as mid, componentid from tblname group by component Id and then inner join that to your base set join on componentid and id

Comment: I'd look at hte CS table and get the needed max ID and componentID first then do the joins for performance really as a subquery.  and I don't know why you join to PE if you're not using any of hte data..

Answer (score 2):

All untested but the basic concepts are there...

Modern approach to least:

- to use cross apply/lateral depending on RDBMS
- use row_number (window function)
- use coorlated sub query
- use sub query and inner join (ANSI -92 assuming you avoid the CTE)

In each of the below I use a common table expression (CTE) just so I don't have to deal with repeating the query or thinking through what elemnts would be needed...

USing a window function:

```
SELECT ID, AvgStatisticData, component ID
FROM (
  SELECT cs.ID ,AvgStatisticData ,cs.ComponentID
     , row_Number() over (partition by CS.componentID, order by CS.ID Desc) RN 
  FROM PortEvidence pe
  JOIN ComponentStatus cs ON cs.ID=pe.ComponentStatusID
  JOIN Component c ON c.ComponentID= cs.ComponentID
  WHERE c.ComponentType = 48) sub
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY cs.ID DESC
```

Using subquery inner join

```
With CTE AS(
SELECT cs.ID ,AvgStatisticData ,cs.ComponentID 
FROM PortEvidence pe
JOIN ComponentStatus cs ON cs.ID=pe.ComponentStatusID
JOIN Component c ON c.ComponentID= cs.ComponentID
WHERE c.ComponentType = 48)
SELECT A.** 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(ID) maxID, componentID FROM CTE Group by ComponentID)
 on A.ID = B.MAXID
and A.ComponentID = B.ComponentID
ORDER BY cs.ID DESC
```

Or using more modern approach assuming SQL Server using table value functions and cross apply

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT cs.ID ,AvgStatisticData ,cs.ComponentID 
FROM PortEvidence pe
JOIN ComponentStatus cs ON cs.ID=pe.ComponentStatusID
JOIN Component c ON c.ComponentID= cs.ComponentID
WHERE c.ComponentType = 48)

SELECT B.* 
FROM CTE A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM CTE B
             WHERE A.ID = B.ID
               and A.ComponentID = B.ComponentID 
             ORDER BY ID Desc) B

ORDER BY cID DESC
```

OR use a coorlated subquery and exists.

```
With CTE AS (SELECT cs.ID ,AvgStatisticData ,cs.ComponentID 
FROM PortEvidence pe
JOIN ComponentStatus cs ON cs.ID=pe.ComponentStatusID
JOIN Component c ON c.ComponentID= cs.ComponentID
WHERE c.ComponentType = 48 
ORDER BY cs.ID DESC)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE  A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT max(ID) MAXID, ComponentID
  FROM CTE B
  GROUP BY ComponetID
  HAVING B.MAXID = A.ID
     and B.ComponetID = A.ComponentID)
```

Comment: you are a saint! thank you!

Comment: Just a few options it all depends on RDBMS and version really.  and volume of data etc.  But the cross apply is the most "Modern" approach while the row_number is probably the most frequently used or the "exists"

Comment: RDBMS was tagged as SQL server from the start?

Comment: But not version. Suppose I could avoided the lateral reference